# JSON::ParserErrorをハンドリングしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

railsでウェブサイトを作っています。

その中にJSONをパースする処理があります。
これ自体はうまく言っているのですが、わざと変な文字を与えると`JSON::ParserError`となってしまい、エラー画面になります。

「パースエラーの場合はこうする」といった処理を書きたいのですが、どうやってやればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

Ruby で例外 (`JSON::ParserError` など) を捕捉するには、`rescue` を利用します。

```
require "json"

json = '{"fate": "testarossa'
begin
  hash = JSON.parse(json)
  p hash
rescue JSON::ParserError => e
  $stderr.puts "ERROR: #{e}"
end
```

`rescue` については、http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/spec=2fcontrol.html#begin を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

既に基本的な回答は出ていますが、補足で別解もあり得るという例を示したいと思います。

```
require 'json'

s = '{"abc": "aaa"'
s2 = '{"abc": "aaa"}'

t = JSON.parse(s) rescue nil  # t にnilが代入
t = JSON.parse(s2) rescue nil # t に{abc: 'aaa'} が代入
```

Answer (score 2):

ウェブサイトを作っていて、変な文字を与えた時にエラー画面になるということは、フォームでJSON形式のテキストを入力していて、そのエラー処理を行いたいということでしょうか？

scaffoldで、たとえば以下のようなモデルを作成したとします。

```
rails g scaffold JsonArticle body:text
```

その場合、`app/models/json_article.rb` に次のようなvalidationを追加すれば、フォームの入力に対してエラー表示を出すことが出来ます。

```
class JsonArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_each :body do |r,a,v|
    json = JSON.parse v rescue nil
    r.errors.add a, "JSONのフォーマットが正しくありません" if json.nil?
  end
end
```

[image: JSONのパース失敗画面]